# How to search column based on json column in PostgreSQL

Tags: postgresql

I have JSON column like this

**data (column name)**

```
row 1 [58,96,36,196,25,23] 
row 2 [26,654,269,22,96]
```

how to write a query

`$user = 96`;

how to search `$user` using PostgreSQL database, how do we write a query using PostgreSQL database, based on `$user` search entire columns of the table

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use [JSON functions](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.3/functions-json.html), something like:

```
with table_with_json as (
    select '[58,96,36,196,25,23]'::json json_column union all
    select '[26,654,269,22,96]'::json
)
select 
    twj.json_column 
from 
    table_with_json twj 
where 
    exists (select t.value from json_array_elements(twj.json_column) t where t.value::text = $user::text);
```

Comment: bro, i want count

Comment: bro, count what? rows which array contain "96" or element in array?

Comment: bro, change "select twj.json_column" to "select count(*)" in my query

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you are using `jsonb` (which is highly recommended) you can use the contains operator `@>`:

```
select *
from the_table
where data @> '96'::jsonb
```

If you are using Postgres 12, you can also use the new JSONB path expression:

```
select *
from the_table
where data @? '$[*] ? (@ == 96)'
```

Comment: bro, i want count

Comment: @user3544162: nowhere in your question do you use the word "count". You should edit your question and add the expected output

Comment: @user3544162: if you need a "count" use `select count(*) from .. where`